# Internal Chrome app to load from web and locally cache its files

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have own Chrome App. But it's for internal use only, so I don't want to publish it in Chrome Web Store. But I need to update it once in a while. Right now I always delete the app from Chrome and load new files from USB flash.

So I am looking for automated or semi-automated solution how to update Chrome App which is not published. My idea is to have some really simple basic Chrome app which will check for updates on start. If there is new version on my web, it will download HTML+CSS+JS files and cache them locally (probably localStorage ?) and use them until new version is found.

I think it is possible, probably there exists some solution to this already, but I haven't found it yet. Thanks for any help and hints.

Comment: Why can't you publish it privately?

Answer (score 0):

This [page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting) outlines how you can host your own private Web Store server. (Basically a **.crx** serving web server) There are a few caveats and provisos, but I would think this would be the easiest way to keep your apps up to date.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that page, but there is also stated: "As of Chrome 33, Windows users can only download extensions hosted in the Chrome Web store, except for installs via enterprise policy or developer mode (see Protecting Windows users from malicious extensions)". Which kinds of makes this useless and I am looking for another solution :-(

Comment: Enterprise policy is a non-starter for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check Last-Modified using xhr. If Last-Modified has changed, then upload the new files using xhr and save them using the [fileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) (in this case, you will be prompted to choose the file) in root directory of app or use [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage). It works for me.

Also you can use [chrome.syncFileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/syncFileSystem).